# Getting signal strength

Tags: java, android, telephony, signal-strength

I want to know how to get CDMA / GSM signal strength using Android.

Note : I used getCdmaDbm() method but it always returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

use PhoneStateListener 's onSignalStrengthsChanged for getting SignalStrength:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(srvcName);  
AndroidPhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new AndroidPhoneStateListener (this);  
telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,      
PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    public class AndroidPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public static int signalStrengthValue;

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
                if (signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() != 99)
                    signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() * 2 - 113;
                else
                    signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
            } else {
                signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
            }
        }

    }
```

Permission :

```
<uses-permission Android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: isGsm() : This method always return true although I set 'Network mode = WCDA only' in setting menu on real device.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html  retrun true is it's for GSM

Comment: Dear Imran, Thank you very much for your kind help. Actually I am very confusing about the command signalStrengthValue = signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();  Is this command using to get the EcIo/RSCP for GSM 3G(WCDMA) or for CDMA2000?  I would like to get the RSCP/EcIo for GSM3G.  Do you have any idea?  Thank you very much in advance ... I am cracking my head for so long... I wish you could enlighten me .. :)

Comment: The CDMA signal strength I get is a negative value like -73, what is that in terms of percentage displayed on the notification bar?